# Registering a dummy model in Django admin to control multiple models data

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Is it possible to register a dummy model (Does not exist in db) that will display data from multiple models in one page?

Maybe just list all objects and when use click on one, a new webpage is opened with details of the clicked on objects? Which is usually this view:

`admin:{app_name}/{model_name}/{object_id}/change`

Comment: How are the objects related? Do these models have a common "parent" that could display this data?

Comment: No. They are not related.

Answer (score 0):

The closest standard solution to what you want are Django inlines:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#using-generic-relations-as-an-inline

I fail to see how you could create a model not present in the db.